# iOS keypad not getting hidden after upgrade to iOS 10 in angular js

Tags: ios, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ios10

I have recently updated device to iOS 10 and facing issues with hiding iOS keypad when i switch from one view to another.It was working well with iOS 9.3.

Programmatically what i have done is, i was intercepting some element and auto focusing one input box when i navigate to second view. And when i move back to first view it was getting hidden but now with 10.0 it doesn't hide it automatically.

Because of privacy concern i am not able to post my code here but this is an angular code where i have written a directive which intercepts clicks on input box in the second view and auto focuses the same which in turn makes keypad popping up.

Now my requirement is to hide this keypad when i move back to first view.

As iOS 10 is very recently released any help or suggestion on this will be greatly appreciated.

N.B: Everything works well with iOS 8 and 9.

Here is what i have tried:

Tried hiding active DOM element.

```
document.activeElement.blur();
```

Also tried calling blur using target property of $element by passing that to my link function in the directive.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is a bug in safari. I had the same issue today and was able to reproduce it with this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/Lz652478/6/

It looks like if an input is removed from the dom via a `touch` event, the keyboard will become sticky. I've been able to get around it in my app by manually calling `blur` at the start of my event handler, before the route changes and the input is removed from the dom.

Comment: Calling blur() didn't fix it for me. Any idea why? I'm using React, but the concept is the same.